# gapi authorize returns access_denied from website on mobile but works from desktop

Tags: javascript, gmail, send, google-api-js-client, authorize

I have a web application which sends an email using gmail api.
The email sends from Google chrome desktop version but not from a mobile (android 10).
At the bottom of my html, I include this script...

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
```

My authorize code looks like:

```
checkAuth: function () {
    var self = this;
    gapi.auth2.authorize({
        client_id: *myClientId*,
        scope: *myScopes*,
        prompt: 'none',
        response_type: 'permission',
        login_hint: '*my email address*'
    }, self.handleAuthResult);
}
```

The response I get is:

```
{"error":"immediate_failed","error_subtype":"access_denied"}
```

I suspect the issue is in my app credentials in the google cloud platform but I don't know how to tell it to accept use from a mobile.

- API restrictions: 'Gmail API'
- Application restrictions: none

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that your mobile browser isn't logged in. You've said `prompt: 'none',` but I suspect  Google wants to interact with the user.

Comment: Yep. When I remove this, I am asked to login in a different tab. Not the functionality I am looking for but I will investigate further and let you know how I get on. Cheers for your help.

Comment: you need to deal with all the different possible situations you encounter. Ie. no user logged in, wrong user logged in, multiple users logged in, permission revoked, all of which will require some user-google interaction. Your problem is definitely not mobile-vs-desktop